# GitLab Unicorn Service crashes all the time, 502 Error

Tags: debian, unicorn, gitlab

I used the Installer of Gitlab CE and so far everything looks well. Then when finished the installation I always got 502 Error on my website, since then I did a little research, then I saw that my gitlab service unicorn restarts/crashes every 10 seconds, so I assume this is the reason why I get 502, but I don't know why it crashes all the time. How can I prevent this? I'm using Debian 7.6 and the newest gitlab version

```
run: nginx: (pid 4919) 953s; run: log: (pid 2236) 1642s
run: postgresql: (pid 2239) 1642s; run: log: (pid 2238) 1642s
run: redis: (pid 2233) 1642s; run: log: (pid 2232) 1642s
run: sidekiq: (pid 3323) 1332s; run: log: (pid 2230) 1642s
run: unicorn: (pid 8153) 2s; run: log: (pid 2234) 1642s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following in the stderr

```
I, [2014-08-19T22:10:48.807830 #3843]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2014-08-19T22:10:53.127464 #3843]  INFO -- : listening on addr=127.0.0.1:8080 fd=11
I, [2014-08-19T22:10:53.127774 #3843]  INFO -- : unlinking existing socket=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket
I, [2014-08-19T22:10:53.127900 #3843]  INFO -- : listening on addr=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket fd=12
E, [2014-08-19T22:10:53.195390 #3843] ERROR -- : Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

So I assume I have too low memory... I have 512 MB

Found this in gitlabHq

> 512MB is the absolute minimum but we do not recommend this amount of memory. You will either need to configure 512MB or 1.5GB of swap space. With 512MB of swap space you must configure only one unicorn worker. With one unicorn worker only git over ssh access will work because the git over http access requires two running workers (one worker to receive the user request and one worker for the authorization check). If you use SSD storage and configure 1.5GB of swap space you can use two Unicorn workers, this will allow http access but it will still be slow.
>   1GB supports up to 100 users (we highly recommend adding al least 1GB of swap space, this is a must if you have individual repositories under 250MB)